# Was the Caribbean Sea a closed sea during the last glaciation?

Tags: oceanography, stratigraphy, paleogeography

Taking a look at Google Earth the straits between the Caribbean Sea and the Atlantic Ocean are not very deep.

[image]

The sealevel during the last glaciation was 120 meters lower than the present level.

Was the Caribbean Sea a closed or semi-closed sea during the last glaciation or the straits were deep enough to make it a connected sea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Eartworm I learned today I was totally incorrect: the straits are more than 2000 meters deep.

[image]

[Tool to see bathymetry, navionics.com](https://webapp.navionics.com/?lang=en#boating@3&key=o%7BkwA%7CukyM)

Comment: Just sayin' it's not a citeable source for bathymetry, strictly spoken, though the data in there is surely better than google (o wonder) because based on official nautical charts.

Comment: @Earthworm I took the liberty of including it as an answer, even short. Thanks, I was totally wrong.